# Distributing an ios app with fastlane pilot

Tags: ios, iphone, fastlane, fastlane-deliver

I'm trying to distribute my ios application with fastlane pilot command using --testers_file_path option. An application is uploaded to the iTunes Connect but unfortunately internal testers are not updated in iTunes Connect and the email is not sent to the testers. Unfortunately there is no enough information about how should I use testers_file_path option. 
So far I've tried:

- write only emails of the testers (separated by comma)
- write the first name and the second name of the testers (John Doe,John Doe)
- download testers.csv file with "pilot list" and use it for distribution

So the questions are

- how should I distribute application with fastlane pilot?
- should I add testers manually in iTunes Connect to make testers_file_path option work?
- what should be the format of the testers.csv file for the testers_file_path option?

Comment: did you find out by now?